# spring aop advice methods in a subclass

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I want to advice a particular method in all class that extends or implements a particular interface or abstract class. How can this be achieved using spring aop 2.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the pointcut expression:

```
within(some.package.MyInterface+)
```

The plus (`+`) means "this class/interface and all subclasses/implementors".

[AspectJ Subtype patterns](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#d0e5943).

Comment: Thanks for super quick answer

Comment: I have a bunch of class that I want to advice, does all the classes need to be spring managed. If so, do all of them require an entry in the applicationContext.xml

Comment: Yes they have to be Spring-managed beans (so you can't generally do aop on business POJOs). You don't need xml entries for every one if you use `@Component` and `<context:component-scan/>`.